# Margem quebrando layout no Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando fazer um row com rows aninhados mas com um espaçamento entre eles, sem o espaçamento o layout fica beleza, mas ao adicionar a margem o layout quebra!

O que estou tentando fazer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado que obtive em minhas tentativas:
http://jsfiddle.net/ywJ7k/1/

Comment: No seu exemplo ele está assim http://fiddle.jshell.net/ywJ7k/1/show/ ?

Comment: Exatamente @SamirBraga !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A minha abordagem para apresentar dados tabulares é utilizar uma tabela.

A grelha que o Bootstrap utiliza é adequada para a estrutura de um web-site de forma a que o mesmo responda aos diversos dispositivos e resoluções sem grande dor de cabeça para o programador.

No que respeita à apresentação de informação, deves utilizar *markup* que corresponda ao tipo de informação a ser apresentada. Temos que ter em mente as aplicações que recolhem dados com base na *markup* em uso de forma a auxiliarem os utilizadores.

## Resultado Final

[**Demonstração no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/YQbyq/)

Podes reduzir e aumentar a largura da janela de *preview* do JSFiddle para veres a informação a ser adaptada ao espaço existente.

[image: Captura de Tela do JSFiddle]

**HTML**

Para o HTML, tentei utilizar o mínimo de *markup* possível mas ao mesmo tempo garantir que nos diversos dispositivos vamos ter um comportamento homogéneo.

A minha solução passa por termos um contentor (`.container`) com uma linha (`.row`) e uma coluna que ocupa toda a largura do contentor (`.col-md-12`) de forma a termos uma grelha que se adapta e responde às alterações de resolução do ecrã.

Dentro da coluna temos então um cabeçalho e uma tabela com os dados a apresentar:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <h5 class="app-header text-center">
                <strong>Núcleo Regional da Diretoria de Araguaína</strong>
                <br />
                (mock,  mock,  mock,  mock,  mock,  mock,  mock)
            </h5>

            <table class="app-table-info">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3" class="text-center">
                            Plantão
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2">
                            Defensor Público:
                            <br/>
                            <strong>Fabricio Silva Brito</strong>
                            <br/>
                            Servidor:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Período
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Telefone
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Início 07/03 as 18h00
                            <br/>
                            Término 07/03 as 18h00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            (92) 3232-3232
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

Para o CSS criei classes com o prefixo `app-` para que sejam perfeitamente distintas de qualquer outra classe que o Bootstrap utiliza. Desta forma sabes quando um estilo teu está a ser aplicado ou subscrito pela *framework*:

```css
/* Cabeçalho Verde */
.app-header{
    background: #178F8D;
    color: #fff;
    line-height:1.4em;
    padding:5px 0;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

/* Tabela com Informações */
.app-table-info{
    background: #E6E7E9;
    color: #3A3A3A;
    width:100%;
}
.app-table-info th,
.app-table-info td{
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom:6px solid #fff;
}
.app-table-info th{
    background: #BEBFC1;
    color: #178F8D;
}
.app-table-info td{
    height:60px;
}
.app-table-info tr:first-child td:first-child{
    vertical-align:top;
    border-right:6px solid #fff;
}
.app-table-info td:last-child{
    border-left:6px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: Imaginei que acabaria utilizando tabelas mesmo! Resposta mais completa!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, só não inseri, os espaçamentos em branco, porque de momento não tenho um editor próprio, e realmente esqueci-me como inseri-los manualmente.

```
<div class="block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="block_header">
                <b>Núcleo Regional da Diretoria de Araguaína</b><br>
                (mock,  mock,  mock,  mock,  mock,  mock,  mock)
            </div>

            <div class="block_subheader">
                <b>Plantão</b>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4 info">
                Defensor Público:<br>
                <b>Fabricio Silva Brito</b><br>
                Servidor:<br>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 info">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Período</th>
                        <th>Telefone</th>
                    </tr>    
                    <tr>
                        <td>Início 07/03 as 18h00<br/>
                            Término 07/03 as 18h00</td>
                        <td>(92) 3232-3232</td>
                    </tr>    
                </table>    

            </div> 

        </div>
```

A CSS ficou assim:

```
  .block_header{
background: #178F8D;
color: #fff;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
margin: 3px;
```

}

```
  .block_subheader{
background: #BEBFC1;
color: #178F8D;    
text-align: center;    
padding-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
```

}

```
  .info{
background: #E6E7E9;
color: #3A3A3A;
margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
padding: 5px;
height: 100%;
float:left;
```

}

```
   .separator{
padding: 0px 0 23px;
float:left;
```

}